# http request object params in javascript not recognized

Tags: javascript, axios, httprequest, contentful

I have this API url that I have test in postman and it works.

https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/master/entries/?select=fields&content_type=events&fields.eventType=vue

As you can see I have **fields.eventTypes** because that's the way I have to do it according to the docs from contentful : https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/relational-queries/

My problem is that when I use **axios** I want to pass the params object as follow.

```
const CONTENTFUL_PARAMS = {
  select: 'fields',
  fields.eventType: 'vue', //js doesn't like this line
  content_type: 'events', 
};
```

I have also tried

```
const CONTENTFUL_PARAMS = {
  select: 'fields',
  fields: {
    eventType: 'vue' //got error 400 in the response
  },
  content_type: 'events', 
};
```

I know I can put everything in one string and do string concat put I don't want to do it that way. How can I achieve that I want to do in a Object that contains the parameters.

```
return axios.get(BASE_URL, { params: CONTENTFUL_PARAMS });
```

Comment: You're missing `,` in `fields.eventType` and `fields: {}`.

Comment: @ÖmürcanCengiz sorry I was editing the params inside of this page. I actually had the commas in my real code, but still don't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like that

```
const CONTENTFUL_PARAMS = {
   select: 'fields',
   "fields.eventType": 'vue',
   content_type: 'events'
};
```